# Триггер в SQL

Tags: sql

Возник к Вам ещё вопрос. Делаю триггер. Есть две колонки с датами, сначала хочу рассчитать с помощью триггера разность в днях между этими датами, а потом от 30 отнять получившееся число...

Разность считается нормально, а со второй частью проблемка: работает некорректно. Что подскажете, вот какой код:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR1
ON Table1
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Table1
set KolvoDays=DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,FinishedDate)
UPDATE Table1
set Ostatok=30-(select KolvoDays from inserted where inserted.NumID=NumID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update в триггере написан неправильно. Нужно использовать предложение FROM, если это SQL Server.

Опять же, если это SQL Server, то триггер вообще не нужен. Сделайте столбец Остаток вычисляемым столбцом, т.е. напишите туда формулу:

```
30 - DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,FinishedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @KolvoDays=KolvoDays from inserted where inserted.NumID=NumID

set Ostatok=30-@KolvoDays
```

Comment: Не въеду, про переменную понятно, там все работает, а с остатком так и остается проблема...

 ALTER TRIGGER TR1
 ON Table1
 FOR INSERT,UPDATE
 AS
 declare @KolvoDays int 
 UPDATE Holiday
 set KolvoDays=DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,FinishedDate)
 select @KolvoDays=KolvoDays from inserted where inserted.NumlID=NumID
 set Ostatok=30-@KolvoDays

В итоге в последней строчке:

>Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: > set Ostatok=30-@KolvoDays

Это же не update, значит нужно объявить переменную и написать так

set @Ostatok=30-@KolvoDays